# PowerShell: How to transform hastable array values like this?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

Given this PowerShell:

```
$groupsToProcess = [ordered]@{
    groupName = @('group1', 'group2')
    ou = @('ou1', 'ou2')
}

$groupsToProcess.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value
}
```

The output is:

```
group1
group2
ou1
ou2
```

How to I make it so that the order is:

```
group1
ou1
group2
ou2
```

In other words, per iteration I would like to use one value from the first key with one value from the second key.

I can't wrap my head around this.

**EDIT**:
Ideally, it would be easy to maintain the values at the top of the script such as this:

```
$groupName = @(
  'group1',
  'group2',
   etc.
)

$ou = @(
  'ou1',
  'ou2',
   etc.
)
```

Comment: Why not using CSV data if there's a relation between the groups and OUs? Or you could use a nested array where you store the proup together with the according OU.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: If you insist on using two unrelated arrays you could use a `for` loop to enumerate the array members with their index. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf I'd rather not bring in data from an external .csv if that's what you mean. Using a nested array? Where exactly?

Comment: How do you populate those data in your hashtable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends pretty much what you're actually trying to do and how you populate your arrays ....

I'd prefer CSV data like this

```
$CSVData = @'
Group,OU
Group1,OU1
Group2,OU2
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($Item in $CSVData) {
    'process {0} and {1}' -f $Item.Group, $Item.OU
}
```

The Output looks like this:

```
process Group1 and OU1
process Group2 and OU2
```

Or if you want to use unrelated arrays ...

```
$groupName = @('group1', 'group2')
$ou = @('ou1', 'ou2')

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $groupName.Count; $i++) {
    'process {0} and {1}' -f $groupName[$i], $ou[$i]
}
```

The output looks the same ...

```
process group1 and ou1
process group2 and ou2
```

Or you could use nested arrays like this:

```
$NestedArray = @(@('Group1', 'ou1'),@('Group2', 'ou2'))

foreach ($Item In $NestedArray) {
    $Item
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Group1      
ou1
Group2      
ou2
```

Comment: Populating the data should ocurr at the top of the script whenever new pairs have to be evaluated in the script within different functions doing other stuff. But your examples do exactly what I was looking for. Three different ways, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd prefer to have input data always *outside* the script. The best way to provide them should be as parameters for a function or script. ;-)

Comment: Okay makes sense, will keep that in mind.